# Wrong headers when importing table to dataframe from DB2 Warehouse in IBM DSX notebook

Tags: python, dataframe, db2, data-science-experience

When attempting to read a table from DB2 into a Pandas dataframe in DSX:

```
df = IdaDataFrame(idadb_dashdb, 'SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME').as_dataframe()
```

...I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42S22', '[42S22] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]
>   SQL0206N  "XXXID" is not valid in the context where it is used.
>   SQLSTATE=42703\n')

By not converting the dataframe to Pandas

```
df = IdaDataFrame(idadb_dashdb, 'SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME')
```

and listing the column names (*df.columns*), I see the columns of a similarly named table, under a different schema, in addition to the columns I want.

Calling

```
df.head()
```

results in the following error:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 8 elements

Comment: ...lemme guess, you're trying to tag to the iSeries?  What are table/schema name lengths?  Is there an `ALIAS` in effect?  Can you just specify the columns you want?

Comment: Bug report submitted on the same issue on github: https://github.com/ibmdbanalytics/ibmdbpy/issues/24